# Proper way to add HTML to the page and access Jquery as well as the users current tab?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome-extension

I am trying to learn how to write a chrome extension. What I am looking for is the ability for to access the current page the user is on. I would like to append some of my own html to the current page the user is accessing. I then want to be able to see which element the user is currently clicking on the page.

I have figured out how to access the tab and run some javascript. But I am unclear how to append some HTML to that page. I also want to bring in jquery.

Here is what I have...

```
{
   "background": {
      "scripts": [ "jquery.min.js", "background.js"]
   },
   "browser_action": {
      "default_icon": "icon128.png",
      "default_title": "Test"
   },
   "description": "Make API's from regular websites",
   "icons": {
      "128": "icon128.png",
      "16": "icon16.png",
      "48": "icon48.png"
   },

   "manifest_version": 2,
   "name": "Test",
   "permissions": [ "tabs", "http://*/*", "https://*/*" ],
   "version": "0.2"
}
```

Background.js

```
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab) {
    chrome.tabs.executeScript(tab.id, {file: "bookmarklet.js"})
});
```

bookmarklet.js

```
(function() { 
    console.log($('.stuff'))
    console.log(document.getElementById('yt-masthead'))
    //open('http://www.google.com/'+encodeURIComponent(document.location.href),'_self').focus(); 
}
)();
```

When I run the program I am finding that I do not have access to jquery. I thought adding it to background in scripts gives me access? I also am unsure how/where I would store the html I want to append to the tab.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off, you can probably drop the scary permissions in favor of the [`activeTab` permission](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/activeTab).

Second, to have jQuery you need to inject it yourself before your other script. Since injecting is asynchronous, make sure you chain it properly:

```
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab) {
    chrome.tabs.executeScript(tab.id, {file: "jquery.min.js"}, function(){
        chrome.tabs.executeScript(tab.id, {file: "bookmarklet.js"});
    });
});
```

Third, you probably want to generate the requisite HTML using jQuery in your content script, `bookmarklet.js`. Or at least store it there in a variable. It's easier to do it on the content script side, but if you have to do it in the background, you should check out [Message Passing](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging).